# How to convert certain words to another word

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have a field that is a short form for a certain word. For example: EXT is Extension

When the word is displayed in my report, I need it to show Extension. There are a list of words that I need converted. So how do I convert a certain list of words to another word but if the word is not on my list in the formula, then keep it the same as it is.

If EXT then Extension
If APP then Appointment
Otherwise, keep the field as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Define a formula named `AnotherWord` for example. It contains the following code:

```
IF {Word} = "EXT" Then
  "Extension"
Else IF {Word} = "APP" Then
  "Appointment"
ELSE
  {Word}
```

You can add additional options as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks Zeina. So if I want to keep Else Word the same as it is if it doesnt fit the criteria above, how would I do that.

Comment: Like the last part. If it doesnt fit EXT or APP, then keep it the same as it is.

Comment: exactly, as @DesmondJenkins said: the last part that contains only else, it displays the word as it is.